# Safe Unicode Dingbats in Email

Tags: unicode, cross-platform

I'm writing a system to send out HTML formatted email and have discovered the dingbats and other symbols in some unicode fonts - these seem perfect for replacing images in the email.

But, if I find a use a character, how can I know if it will been seen on most/all systems? - I cant seem to find a list of cross-platform unicode symbols.

Also, am I correct that if the unicode character you specify is not in the selected font, a fallback font will be used - this appear to be true on the Mac, but I have no idea about Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the display of Unicode depends entirely on what font set is installed on the recipient's computer.  There is no such thing as a "list of cross-platform unicode symbols".  Unicode by itself is pretty much cross-platform but there are hardly any fonts which cover the whole Unicode repertoire in any particular point in time (consider how often Unicode is updated, too).

Comment: That sounds like don't do it - it's not reliable enough??

Comment: @Ben: Use any Unicode code point you want.  It’s not your fault if somebody else doesn’t have a font.

Comment: @tchrist: If I send out an email full of squares or other garbage - I think the client would feel different ?!

Comment: @Ben: Then send a fricking PDF to the poor slob who can’t be bothered to keep an up-to-date system. Code points are code points. They have nothing to do with fonts. If I write a program that parses out a mail message, believe me, absolutely nothing in the code cares one flying fig about fickle fonts. **Code points are code points.** If they’ll legal, use them. If you spend your life worrying about other people’s stupidities, you’ll never get anywhere. Push the edge. Or send ASCII art to the grandpappies. Better yet, write out the letter in longhand and deliver it using the postal service.

Comment: If you are satisfied with HTML email, I guess by definition you are looking for something which doesn't work 100% of the time for 100% of your users.  Anything which was introduced in the Unicode symbol code blocks several years ago will probably work fine 95% of the time for 95% of your target audience.  As another approximation, if it works on a couple of your computers, it's probably fine for your scenario.  Try e.g. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=bullet&preview=entity (I see all but the last one fine in MacOS X; my experience is that Ubuntu is similar).

Comment: As another data point, my iPhone displays the U+1Fxxx character just fine, but the U+26xx and U+29xx code points display as boxes.

Comment: Thanks - I feel I'm closer the the thrust of my question - my Mac is up to date - but I can't see the "legal code point" for a bullet train - my iPhone is up to date, but I can't see the several of the symbols on the bullet page above - Windows 7 misses even more - it feels like a minefield, even before I think about "grandpappies"